# How to make aa spring webclient request post request without body

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

So i want to make a post request with a body

@PostMapping("/create")
public ResponseEntity create() { // returns 201 }

byt calling code has the following

```
 webClient.post()
                .uri(createUrl)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(Mono.empty()))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Void.class);
```

However i get the following message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'body' should be an object, for reactive types use a variant specifying a publisher/producer and its related element type
```

How can i make a post request without a body using webclient

Comment: just remove `.body(...)`

Comment: @Alex nope it doesnt work... i have other post methods that accept body those work fine. But something to do with not having a body in the request

Comment: What exactly doesn’t work? It will sent post request without body

Comment: it doesnt even hit the controller... do i need a content type?

Comment: it depends on your controller but `webClient.post()`without body definitely works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked.

```
webClient.post()
                .uri(url)
                .exchange();
```

Comment: `exchange` is deprecated since 5.3 due to the possibility to leak memory.

Comment: thanks.. im using an older version. il update